# PrintWriter creates file but doesn't print to file

Tags: java, arrays, printwriter

This is a college course assignment that consists of classes TotalSales and TotalSalesTest.In the main program I have created a two dimensional array to output a columnar layout with cross-totals in 4 rows and 5 columns. This program outputs sales totals by row for each sales person(1 - 4) and output by column for products(1 - 5). I have created extra elements in the array to store total for rows and columns. So far both classes compiles. The problem is that although the PrintWriter creates a notepad file, it doesn't print to it. I could use some help on this problem. Here is the code`

```
 //write program in a two diminsional array to output a columnar layout with cross-totals in 4 rows and 5 columns
 //program outputs sales totals by row for each sales person(1 - 4) and output by column for products(1 - 5)
 //create extra elements to store total for rows and columns 
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.*;
 public class TotalSales
 {
 private int salesPerson; //declare class variable  
 private int productNumber;//declare class variable
 private double totalSales;//declare class variable
 private double allSales;
//declare input and output variables
Scanner inFile; //declare inFile variable 
PrintWriter outFile;//declare outFile variable 



  double[][]sales = new double[6][7];//declare array sales


  public void initializer()
  {
  try
  {
  inFile  = new Scanner( new File( "assign06.txt" ) );
  outFile = new PrintWriter( "MonthlyTotalSales.txt" );
  outFile.flush(); 
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e)
  {
     System.out.println("The input file could not be found!");
     System.exit(1); 
  }

 while(inFile.hasNext()) //while there is data to process… 
  {
 salesPerson = inFile.nextInt();//reads salesPerson
 productNumber = inFile.nextInt();//reads productNumber
 totalSales = inFile.nextDouble();//reads totalSales
 sales[salesPerson][productNumber]+=totalSales;

 sales[salesPerson][6]+=totalSales;

 sales[5][productNumber]+=totalSales;

 allSales += totalSales;
  } //end while loop
 printDetails(sales);//call method printDetails
 finishUp();//call method finishUp

 }//end initializer

 public void printDetails(double[][] array)
 {
outFile.println("\t1\t2\t3\t4\t5");

 for (int salesPerson =1; salesPerson <5; salesPerson++)
{
  outFile.print(salesPerson+ "      ");
  for(int productNumber=1; productNumber <=array.length; productNumber++)
     outFile.print(array[salesPerson][productNumber]+"    ");

  //end inside loop
  outFile.println();
 }//end outside loop


 outFile.print("Total: \t  ");
 for(int salesTotal=1; salesTotal<array.length; salesTotal++)
 {   
  outFile.print(array[5][salesTotal] +" ");
 }
 outFile.print(allSales);


 outFile.println();


    outFile.print("  ");        

    outFile.println();

  }//end printDetails

 public void finishUp()
 {
 inFile.close();
 outFile.close();
 System.out.println("The program has finished.");

 }//end finishUp

}//end class TotalSales
```

Here is the test program:

```
public class TotalSalesTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TotalSales ts = new TotalSales();
        ts.initializer();
    }//end method main
}
```

Here is the text file for the input:

```
1 1 37.50
1 2 77.00
1 3 68.75
1 4 61.25
1 5 175.00
2 1 45.00
2 2 66.00
2 3 27.50
2 4 49.00
2 5 250.00
3 1 67.50
3 2 33.00
3 4 73.50
3 5 200.00
4 1 15.00
4 2 99.00
4 3 123.75
4 4 85.75
4 5 125.00
1 1 60.00
1 2 88.00
1 3 41.25
1 4 49.00
1 5 225.00
2 1 67.50
2 2 33.00
2 3 27.50
2 4 122.50
2 5 25.00
3 1 60.00
3 2 44.00
3 3 96.25
3 4 36.75
3 5 50.00
4 1 75.00
4 2 11.00
4 3 41.25
4 4 98.00
4 5 125.00
1 1 45.00
1 2 33.00
1 3 27.50
1 4 61.25
1 5 200.00
2 1 52.50
2 2 22.00
2 3 13.75
2 4 36.75
2 5 50.00
3 1 37.50
3 2 88.00
3 3 96.25
3 4 36.75
4 1 37.50
4 2 77.00
4 3 82.50
4 4 73.50
4 5 25.00
1 1 30.00
1 2 88.00
1 3 41.25
1 4 12.25
1 5 175.00
2 1 45.00
2 2 22.00
2 3 68.75
2 4 98.00
3 2 88.00
3 3 41.25
3 4 24.50
4 1 30.00
4 2 88.00
4 3 82.50
4 4 122.50
4 5 175.00
```

Comment: Do you call `finishUp` method anywhere?

Comment: I just called finishUp. Now I working on the other corrections in see in the answers. I got help with this code from a tutor at the college, a student who had taken several programming courses. This is going to take me a while to correct as I look over the suggestions.

Comment: Good luck for your debugging it is nice to see you are actually trying to do it by yourself instead of begging for code

Comment: I just edited this post with some changes to the code. The code is better. Now it does print out a file, but for some reason I get an illegal start of expression in the for loop. So now it won't compile. I even put the for loop in a method but I still get the error message. Can anybody tell me why. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Here is the corrected code. Everything compiles and PrintWriter outputs a file with rows and columns of the monthly sales report, although the columns don't exactly line up as they are suppose to. I spent almost an hour trying to fix it. If anybody got any suggestions on how to line up the columns, please do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `printDetails` before initializing the writer... Move the `printDetails` call after `outFile = new PrintWriter( "MonthlyTotalSales.txt" );`and it should be fine. However, you should have included your constructor since as it is right now, I would think your code throws a `NullPointerException` because the writer is never initialized. You also need to close the file before writing in it, or at least you need to flush.

The whole structure of your code is bad, you should never have a method such as `mainProgram` on a class, you should never use a file as an attribute just to use it in every method, and you should never separate in different methods creation and closing of i/o classes.

Comment: I moved printDetails() and finishUp() methods to end of program. I kept the mainProgram() method because when I deleted it I got a "illegal start of type" error.

Comment: I meant that this is not a good name for a method, this is not imperative programming. There is only one main in a Java application and most of the time it is very short.

Comment: I'll give mainProgram method another name. Although the method main in is TotalSalesTest program. I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't call outFile.close();

Call your finishUp() method once you complete writing in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think your program crashes with a nullpointer on

inFile.hasNext()

because you never actually opened or even instantiated the input file along with the output file in the try/catch block.  Whoops!

change

```
    try
    {
        outFile = new PrintWriter( "MonthlyTotalSales.txt" ); 
    }
```

to

```
    try
    {
        inFile = new Scanner(new File("Input.txt"));
        outFile = new PrintWriter( "MonthlyTotalSales.txt" ); 
    }
```

Comment: As I stated the program compiles. How would I instantiated the input and output file in try catch block? I thought tha's what I did. I got to do some more research on this. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: The compilation is different from the execution, check the definitions. osoblanco is right about your code, however as you never mentionned an NPE I assumed you had initiliatized `inFile` in your constructor. Is that the case ?

Comment: I used the Scanner class method to read the values from the input file. And I created a printer object with outFile = new PrintWriter. I think that's what I did.

Comment: I updated to include how I suggest instantiating the inFile.  Yes, you declared it, and yes you read from it.  But the output from the catch block indicates you planned to actually open the input file in the try, but you only opened the output file.